# A nohup command over SSH in Bamboo doesn't exit

Tags: bash, ssh, bamboo

In a Bamboo server one can setup a Deployment Plan and execute a command with an "SSH Task". I have a task that starts a java process. I wrote following command to start it up, leave it running and exit from the remote server:

```
nohup java -jar project.jar 2>&1 1>/dev/null &
```

With this command the SSH Task is never closed and the Java process output is recorded by the deployment until I log in to the remote server and kill the process. So I looked at an old deployment plan that works and when changing to this:

```
nohup java -jar project.jar </dev/null>/tmp/project.log 2>&1 &
```

the process is left running on the server and the task closes, as expected.
Can anyone explain why the first command doesn't let go, like the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of redirects is important! Specifically, `2>&1` means "Send standard error to where standard output is currently going". In your example:

```
... 2>&1 1>/dev/null ...
```

means "send stderr to the current stdout (i.e. the ssh session), and then redirect stdout to /dev/null" - so it leaves stderr pointing to the ssh session.

In the working example:

```
... >/tmp/project.log 2>&1 ...
```

means "send stdout to a file, and then send stderr to where stdout is pointing" - so both end up going to the file.

Also the working example does

```
</dev/null
```

which ensures standard input is no longer connected to the SSH session; your first example doesn't do that.

In summary, the non-working example leaves both stdin and stderr connected to the SSH session; this generally explains why the ssh task doesn't complete.